# PHP - combining vars with strings in order to create one string

Tags: php, variables

So basically I am trying to save something on my root folder:

```
$xml->save('../datas/' + $randomString + '.xml');
```

But it doesn't work. however, when I do

```
$xml->save('../datas/hi.xml');
```

it does. so I figured, it must be a problem with my var, randomString:

```
$randomString = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789"), 0, $length);
```

So, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: This is not javascript my friend. Use `.` to append strings :O

Comment: It's amazing what google "php combine strings" turns up

Answer (score 5):

You want string concatenation. In PHP the operator for it is `.`, not `+`.

Comment: Well I  come from JS background so, execuse my french. thumbs up

Comment: @user1938653: So maybe some _research effort_?

Comment: Also double quotes gets rid of concatenation, check http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Comment: @user1938653, Even if you do come from a JS background, it's a route for disaster trying to code PHP as if it were JavaScript. Take some time to learn the nuances of PHP. Will help you tons in the long run.